# Babel to translate JSX to JS

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, babeljs

In C#, I get as an input a JSX file and want to translate it to JS. I want to use the babel library, and used this guide:https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation

However, I am getting an exception of type:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCResolutionException' occurred in React.Core.dll

Additional information: Unable to resolve type: React.IReactEnvironment

for this line: ReactEnvironment.Current

I have tried to create a new ASP.NET project, and no exception was thrown and everything worked just fine.

My question is: How can I still use babel in non web project?

Comment: Use the following babel preset [babel-plugin-syntax-jsx](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-jsx/)

Comment: Can you be more specific? I didn't get even to the preset stage. I can't initalize React environment.

Comment: Did you install `Install-Package React.Core` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run an extra initialization step for non Web applications. 
This initialization step is automatically done in Web applications.

If its a console application then use this function,

```
        private static void Initialize()
        {
            Initializer.Initialize(registration => registration.AsSingleton());
            var container = React.AssemblyRegistration.Container;
            // Register some components that are normally provided by the integration library
            // (eg. React.AspNet or React.Web.Mvc6)
            container.Register<ICache, NullCache>();
            container.Register<IFileSystem, SimpleFileSystem>();
        }
```

And call it in the main method.

Take a look at the github console sample app for React.Net

[Link for reference](https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/blob/release-2.5.0/src/React.Sample.ConsoleApp/Program.cs)